# Topological characterisations of freeness and separability?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory

According to wikipedia, a [spectral space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestley_space) is defined to be homeomorphic to the spectrum of some commutative ring. They form a category $Spec$ where we take morphisms to be those whose preimage of open and quasi-compact sets are also as such. An alternative (ring-independent) characterisation is:

> It is compact ordered topological space satisfying the [priestley separation condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestley_space)

Since we have a contravariant functor $F:CRing \rightarrow Spec$; an algebra, which is a morphism of commutative rings $A \rightarrow B$, under application of the functor, goes to $FB \rightarrow FA$, a morphism of Spectral spaces.

Now, what is the topological condition on $FB \rightarrow FA$ when $A \rightarrow B$ (understood as an algebra) is

1. Free?
2. Separable?

Comment: This functor isn't faithful, so there's no reason it should be able to detect things in general.

Comment: (E.g. on fields it tells you nothing, so it's already impossible to characterize separability of field extensions.)

Comment: @Yuan: presumably the functor is faithful when we promote $Spec$ to $Aff$ by decorating them with a structure sheaf? Does the question make any sense then?

Comment: I mean, sure, but now you're not just talking about topology. E.g. on fields you're still just talking about fields.